# Unity C# - Liskov Substitution Principle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, liskov-substitution-principle, solid

I was rewriting some code to practice SOLID and I think my code is failing the Liskov Substitution Principle. I don't know if this code is correct, can someone help me?

That code was created to control camera rotation, position and orientation for a thir person character. I don't know if that methods need to be separated in other classes or if this code is correct.

- My question is related to all the methods of the "AnchorControlForThirdPersonCamera" class, if I must separate them in other classes or not.
- Another thing is the use of the "anchor" variable, do I use that variable in "AnchorControlForThirdPersonCamera " class or in "ThirdPersonCamera " an just return when is necessary?

Obs: That class control the anchor but I don't know it is correct if all this methods should be in the same place.

Class:

```
public class AnchorControlForThirdPersonCamera : MonoBehaviour, IAnchorControlForThirdPersonCamera
{
    [Header("Settings")]
    [SerializeField] private string anchorName = "CameraAnchor";
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0,1,0);

    [Header("Rotation Control")]
    [SerializeField] private string inpMouseX = "Mouse X";
    [SerializeField] private string inpMouseY = "Mouse Y";
    [SerializeField] private float rotationSpeed = 100;
    [SerializeField,Range(1,179)] private float minAxisY = 89;
    [SerializeField,Range(181,359)] private float maxAxisY = 320;

    private Transform anchor;

    public Transform GetAnchor() {
        return anchor;
    }

    public void CreateAnchor()
    {
        if (!anchor)
        {
            anchor = new GameObject(anchorName).transform;
            anchor.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInHierarchy;
        }
    }

    public void CalculateEulerForAnchorRotation()
    {
        float axisMouseX = Input.GetAxis(inpMouseX);
        float axisMouseY = Input.GetAxis(inpMouseY);

        Vector3 anchorEuler = anchor.eulerAngles;
        anchorEuler.y += axisMouseX * rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        anchorEuler.x -= axisMouseY * rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        if (anchorEuler.x > minAxisY && anchorEuler.x < 180) anchorEuler.x = minAxisY;
        if (anchorEuler.x < maxAxisY && anchorEuler.x > 180) anchorEuler.x = maxAxisY;

        anchor.eulerAngles = anchorEuler;
    }

    public void CalculateAnchorPosition(Transform player)
    {
        anchor.position = player.TransformPoint(offset);
    }

    public void OnDestroyAnchor()
    {
        if (anchor)
        {
            Destroy(anchor);
        }
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IAnchorControlForThirdPersonCamera
{
    Transform GetAnchor();

    void CreateAnchor();

    /// <summary></summary>
    void CalculateEulerForAnchorRotation();

    /// <summary>Used in LateUpdate method.</summary>
    /// <param name="player"></param>
    void CalculateAnchorPosition(Transform player);

    void OnDestroyAnchor();
}
```

Main Code:

```
public class ThirdPersonCamera : MonoBehaviour
    {

        private IAnchorControlForThirdPersonCamera _anchorControl;
        
        private ICameraPositionRayForThirdPersonCamera _cameraPositionRay;
        private ICameraPositionForThirdPersonCamera _cameraPosition;
        private ICameraOrientationForThirdPersonCamera _cameraOrientation;

        [SerializeField] private Transform player;
       
        private RaycastHit hitForCameraPos = new RaycastHit();
        private Ray rayForCameraPos;

        private void Awake()
        {            
            if (GetComponent<ICameraPositionRayForThirdPersonCamera>() == null) 
            {
                gameObject.AddComponent<CameraPositionRayForThirdPersonCamera>();
            }
            _cameraPositionRay = GetComponent<ICameraPositionRayForThirdPersonCamera>();

            if (GetComponent<IAnchorControlForThirdPersonCamera>() == null) {
                gameObject.AddComponent<AnchorControlForThirdPersonCamera>();
            }
            _anchorControl = GetComponent<IAnchorControlForThirdPersonCamera>();

            if (GetComponent<ICameraPositionForThirdPersonCamera>() == null)
            {
                gameObject.AddComponent<CameraPositionForThirdPersonCamera>();
            }
            _cameraPosition = GetComponent<ICameraPositionForThirdPersonCamera>();

            if (GetComponent<ICameraOrientationForThirdPersonCamera>() == null)
            {
                gameObject.AddComponent<CameraOrientationForThirdPersonCamera>();
            }
            _cameraOrientation = GetComponent<ICameraOrientationForThirdPersonCamera>();

            _anchorControl.CreateAnchor();
        }

        void Start() {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;

            Transform anchor = _anchorControl.GetAnchor();
            _anchorControl.CalculateEulerForAnchorRotation();
            rayForCameraPos = _cameraPositionRay.CreateRayForCameraPosition(anchor);
            hitForCameraPos = _cameraPosition.SpherecastForCalculateCameraPosition(rayForCameraPos);

            _anchorControl.CalculateAnchorPosition(player);
            rayForCameraPos = _cameraPositionRay.CreateRayForCameraPosition(anchor);
            transform.position = _cameraPosition.GetCameraPosition(rayForCameraPos, hitForCameraPos);
            transform.rotation = _cameraOrientation.GetCameraLookAtTargetPoint(anchor, transform);
        }

        void Update() {
            _anchorControl.CreateAnchor();

            _anchorControl.CalculateEulerForAnchorRotation();
            rayForCameraPos = _cameraPositionRay.CreateRayForCameraPosition(_anchorControl.GetAnchor());
            hitForCameraPos = _cameraPosition.SpherecastForCalculateCameraPosition(rayForCameraPos);
        }

        void LateUpdate()
        {
            Transform anchor = _anchorControl.GetAnchor();
            _anchorControl.CalculateAnchorPosition(player);
            rayForCameraPos = _cameraPositionRay.CreateRayForCameraPosition(anchor);
            transform.position = _cameraPosition.GetCameraPosition(rayForCameraPos, hitForCameraPos);
            transform.rotation = _cameraOrientation.GetCameraLookAtTargetPoint(anchor, transform);
        }

        private void OnDestroy() {
            _anchorControl.OnDestroyAnchor();
        }
    }
```

I tryed to implement liskov subistituition principle in this code, but when I tryed to implement in the methods related a anchor control (used to control the position, rotation and orientation of the camera) the code become strange and I don't know if I write correctly.

Comment: It sounds like 2 separate problems: bugs in the code, and wondering if it follows LSP properly?  Also, LSP is a "good thing" and is not always an absolute law to follow 100%.  Sometimes you want a "square" subclass and to just make sure you never try to use it as a "rectangle".  Sometimes other "bad" things like a "god class" work well for an app :)

Comment: Exactly, I'll keep what you said in my mind, my question covers the SOLID principles, but I was focusing PSL on that part, maybe that code I made is correct, thank you for your help :)

Comment: SOLID and PSL etc are **good practice principles** .. most of the time in coding there are huge grey areas and the "one correct solution / implementation of a principle" is usually not a thing ;) It often comes down to opinions and personal preferences. E.g. `do I use that variable in "AnchorControlForThirdPersonCamera " class or in "ThirdPersonCamera " an just return when is necessary?` this pretty much depends on your definitions and which class should be responsible for what exactly ...